# How to change position in Bootstrap dropdown down arrow?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-canvas

I try to change position in my dropdown down arrow. But can't find any css or anyplace to change this. I trying using `background-position-x: ;` and it's not working. Hope your help for this. Can I let me know how can I catch this arrow using from separate css class?. Appciate your support!

This sample of [screen IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiwWP.png)

This is HTML code

```
<select class="sb-default-selectbox selectpicker btn-outline-default" 
        data-native-menu="false" 
        data-form="ui-btn-up-a"
        tabindex="-1" 
        style="color: #fff; 
               border-radius: 30px;
               width: 100%; 
               border-color: #fff0; 
               background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); 
               border: none; 
               height: 45px;">
    <option value="NIC">NIC</option>
    <option value="PID">passport</option>
    <option value="DLID">DLID</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add your css and make it [runnable code](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @RayeesAC This is a normal code one. Can I let me know how to find that dwopdown arrow in bootstrap ? this is bootstrap one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added **fa fa** icon instead of default icon.

if you want change position of icon, change the below code as you needs.

```
.fa{
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
}
```

Try this instead,

```css
.selectpicker{
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #111;
  background-color:#8f8579;
  border: none;
  height: 45px;
  padding:0 20px;
   /* remove the original arrow */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position:relative;
}
.fa{
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="selectpicker" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <option value="NIC">NIC</option>
    <option value="PID">passport</option>
    <option value="DLID">DLID</option>
</select>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks and Can I let me know how can change position dropdown arrow icon?

Comment: Try now this , if you change position by `right` property of **fa** icon.

Comment: It's working!. I not use `.fa{
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
}` this css. But it's work. Thank You!